# Android Bluetooth app wont run due to Null pointer error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Bluetooth app won't run due to Null pointer exceptions. No errors, but I can't see to connect to the emulator as the app just crashes every time. Even if I try sample GitHub codes, it won't run either. I'll post code and catlog and anything else you need. Thank you for your help

```
package com.example.bluetooth_demoproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT_ = 1;

TextView mBluetoothStatus, mPairedDevicelist;
ImageView mBluetoothIcon;
Button mOnButton, mOffButton, mDiscoverableButton, mPairedDevices, 
mSendImage;

BluetoothAdapter mBlueAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
    mBluetoothStatus = findViewById(R.id.BluetoothStatus);
    mPairedDevicelist = findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
    mBluetoothIcon = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothIcon);
    mOnButton = findViewById(R.id.onButton);
    mOffButton = findViewById(R.id.offButton);
    mDiscoverableButton = findViewById(R.id.discoverableButton);
    mPairedDevices = findViewById(R.id.pairedDevices);
    mSendImage = findViewById(R.id.sendImage);


    //adapter
   BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = 
  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // check if bluetooth is available
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth is not available");
    }
    else {
        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth is available");
        }
        //if Bluetooth isnt enabled, enable it
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
       Intent enableBtIntent = new 
   Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }


    //on button Click
    mOnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                showToast("Turning Bluetooth on...");
                // intent to on bluetooth
                Intent intent = new 
  Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

            }
            else {
                showToast("Bluetooth is already on");
            }

        }
    });

    //discover Bluetooth button
    mDiscoverableButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (!mBlueAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                showToast("Discovering devices..");
                Intent intent = new 
       Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT_);
            }

        }

    });

    // off button click
    mOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                showToast("Turning Bluetooth off...");
                // intent to turn off bluetooth
                mBluetoothIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_off);
            }
            else{
                showToast("Bluetooth is already off");
            }

        }
    });



    //get paired device button click


    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = 
    mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
       if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
           // Retrieve the name and address of the paired devices
           for (BluetoothDevice device: pairedDevices) {
               String deviceName = device.getName();
               String deviceAddr = device.getAddress();
           }
       }





}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
     data) {
     switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                //bluetooth is on
                mBluetoothIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_on);
                showToast("Bluetooth is on");
            }
            else {
                //user is denied turning on Bluetooth
                showToast("Unable to turn on Bluetooth");
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

//toast message function
private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
}

   }



    9-08 22:03:46.371 1510-2830/system_process W/ActivityManager: 
  getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10060 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; 
    limiting output
```

09-08 22:03:46.372 5869-5869/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-08 22:03:46.416 5869-5869/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
09-08 22:03:46.416 5869-5869/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-08 22:03:46.418 5869-5869/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bluetooth_demoproject, PID: 5869
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bluetooth_demoproject/com.example.bluetooth_demoproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bluetooth_demoproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
09-08 22:03:46.431 1510-2232/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.example.bluetooth_demoproject/.MainActivity`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is from line 59: `if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {`

Note: The error message says line 57, but in my text editor it says 59.

A few lines above, you check whether the object `mBluetoothAdapter` was successfully created by checking if it's `== null`. But after that, you call its method: `.isEnabled()`. I think the problem is that `mBluetoothAdapter` is becoming `null` and therefore throws a NullPointerException when you try to access one of its methods.

If I understand correctly, I think the solution would be something like this:

```
// check if bluetooth is available
if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
    mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth is not available");
}
else {
    mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth is available");
    //if Bluetooth isnt enabled, enable it
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new 
            Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
```

This would keep the enabling code away from a `mBluetoothAdapter` with a value of `null`.

Alternativly, you could use `return` to exit the method if BlueTooth isn't available.

```
// check if bluetooth is available
if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
    mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth is not available");
    return;
}
else {
    mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth is available");
    }
    //if Bluetooth isnt enabled, enable it
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
   Intent enableBtIntent = new 
       Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
   startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

This would do the same in a little bit of a cleaner way.

I think the next step for you is to find out why `BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();` is returning `null` instead of the object you want. I don't think the answer to that is in your `MainActivity` method. The device isn't finding a default adapter and that could be the result of numerous problems.

Comment: I just tried using the android sample from the official website for a Bluetooth app, and problem like these always occur. Do you know where I can find a working, updated Bluetooth sample app?